# Highlight data points in a line graph on Excel 2010 or 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a line chart (two series of data) and I need to highlight a specific point in the data. Is it similar to the bar chart where you can just change the color or is there something different?

Answer (score 2):

You can modify formatting of a line chart one point at a time. Click once to select the series, then click once more to select one point. Using the usual formatting dialog, which should be entitled "Format Point" instead of "Format Series", you can then format the individual marker and the individual line segment between the selected point and the previous point.